# How to get the feature names from OneHotEncoder and have them in Pandas data frame

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, k-means, one-hot-encoding

Here is my Python code:

```
encode = OneHotEncoder()
encoded_cols = encode.fit_transform(data[['Sex', 'Housing', 'Saving accounts', 'Checking account',
                                'Purpose']])
cols = encode.get_feature_names(['Sex', 'Housing', 'Saving accounts', 'Checking account',
                                'Purpose'])
df_encode = pd.DataFrame(encoded_cols, columns=cols)
```

I tried to transform the categorical columns to one hot encoding. Then get the features names.

I get the error:

```
ValueError: Shape of passed values is (1000, 1), indices imply (1000, 20)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do what you asked for.
But the easiest way is to do the following:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder

columns = ['Sex', 'Housing', 'Saving accounts', 'Checking account',
                                'Purpose']
# this is to generate a random dataframe with values
input_df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, len(columns))), columns=columns)

encoder = OneHotEncoder(sparse_output=False).set_output(transform="pandas")

output_df = encoder.fit_transform(data[columns])
```

This is using scikit-learn `1.2.2`. It will return a dataframe with the correct column names and of course using the OneHotEncoder.

Comment: Thank you so much, here is attempt    `from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
import pandas as pd

encode = OneHotEncoder()
cols = ['Sex', 'Housing', 'Saving accounts', 'Checking account', 'Purpose']
encoded_cols = encode.fit_transform(data[cols])
df_encode = pd.DataFrame(encoded_cols.toarray(), columns=encode.get_feature_names(cols))`

Comment: my solution uses the ```set_ouput``` from sklearn which is better than using ```encode.get_feature_names``` then putting it in a dataframe.

Comment: check the performance of both and you will see the difference.